# J2ee Session Tracking

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

In my servlet (after login) I set the session timeout interval as 30 seconds and also note the sessionID as say X

```
 session.setMaxInactiveInterval(30);
```

The servlet then forwards to a JSP page (intermediate1) which has a link to the second intermediate page (intermediate2). I don't do anything on the page for around 30 seconds (timeout interval) and then forward to the second jsp page (intermediate 2). Here I print the sessionID and it is NOT X. It is another value. How did this happen? Does the container automatically assign a session object to a JSP page if no session already exists? Kindly help.

Comment: There is always a session object. It's either the same as previous request if it did not expire OR a new one if first request or previous session object expired. That's the way it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSP spec (for JSP 2.1/JEE6 it is found in chapter "JSP.1.10.1 The page Directive") describes that the `session` implicit object is on *by default*, so that every call to a JSP will participate in an existing session/create a new session if needed. It *can* be turned off as:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this.

Answer (score 1):

Because of `jsp implicit-object`, then see one of them is 'session'.

So, jsp's implicate object always be there.

In your case, already current session object went off, but jsp api make it newly available.

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interesting link I found on the web that answers my own question. FYI.

http://www.xyzws.com/jspfaq/can-i-prevent-the-creation-of-a-session-in-a-jsp-page/20